# Disconnected metric space

Tags: metric-spaces

In an exercise I found that we can write metric topologies by choosing the distance equal to the length of the shortest path connecting two points; however if the space isn't connected then what "additional step is required" to show that its a metric space / topology?

Comment: Are you talking about a metric on a graph?

Comment: If your space is not connected you are probably going to want to renormalize the metric so that it is bounded by some $A$ on each connected component, and then take a value greater than $A$ to represent the distance between points on different components.

Comment: @arthur Yes, I am....

Comment: As @CaptainLama says, you can normalize the metric so the distance is always less than $1$, so make the distance between points in different connected components $1$.

Comment: Shouldn't there be endpoints / non adjacent points in disconnected parts with a distance less than one as well?